# Displaying Image[path] and Data[Varchar] in a HTML Table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new here and new in php world.
I'm making web page using mysql and php. Need to display on images and data like a search results on another page. In wamp I create a database 
[image: Pic of data base]

This is a search form with php [image: search and php code]

connection whit db is working

this is message

> **( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\vezba
>   3\rezultati-pretrage.php

But im note for sure the problem is only in this line

Blow my head to figuring out this

PLEASE HELP

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM artikli";
if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>id</th>";
                echo "<th>cena</th>";
                echo "<th>model</th>";
                echo "<th>slika</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['cena'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
                echo "</br>";
                header("Content-type: image/png");
                echo '<img src="'.$row['slika'].'"/>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}   

// Close connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Don't post photos of code, post the actual code.

Comment: Your error is probably on this line -> `echo "<td>"."<img src= echo $row['slika']/>"."</td>";` You are already echoing that line, so you don't need to add `echo` before the php variable. Just do -> `echo "<td>"."<img src='". $row['slika']. "' />"."</td>";`

Comment: Thanks Sean for answer this part (line) is working great.
but pop-up a new problem it wont display nothing not even error

Comment: You can't do `header("Content-type: image/png");` in the middle of your html code. You are probably getting a [`headers already sent`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php), but you may not see it if error reporting is turned off. Since your `$row['slika']` is the name of a file, and not an actual image, it is unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to see what the code is, but Line 26 definitely needs to change to this:

```
// i prefer single quoting to double quoting most of the time
// but it's definitely clearer here since you need attributes
echo '<td><img src="'.$row['slika'].'"/></td>';
```

**edit**

You have an `if` here...add an `else` like this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
   // ... code
} else {
  echo 'mysqli error? ';
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Also, if the page is white, you may not be seeing your errors.  Be sure to know [where your php error log is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel);

Comment: Thanks WEBjuju
Your answer is working no more error but funny thing do not display nothing, empty page.
I edited my question here is a useble code

Comment: you may just have a query or file error

Comment: something is wrong for shure. I`ll try different code to solve the problem.
Thank you anyway